# Vuetify/Navigation-Drawer: Can I check if it is expaneded?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I put a `v-card` inside my `v-navigation-drawer` so that it is everywhere accessible. I wrapped the card inside a a `v-list-item` so that I can use an icon in minified version. My goal is to show the icon and hide the card when the navigation is minified. Vice versa if expanded.

The navigation's expand-on-hover property is currently determined when the window is resized.

I tried to use `@mouseenter` and `@mouseleave`but the methods aren't triggert.

Navigation:

```
<template>
    <v-navigation-drawer
    :permanent="permanent"
    :app="app"
    :expand-on-hover="getExpandOnHover"
    class="d-flex flex-column"
    @mouseenter="mouseenter"

    >
        <v-list nav class="py-0">
            <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title class="headline">App</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>

            <v-divider></v-divider>

            <v-list-item v-for="item in items" :key="item.title" link :to="item.to">
                <v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
                </v-list-item-icon>

                <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title>
                        {{ item.title }}
                    </v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
        </v-list>

        <v-divider/>

        <v-list>
            <v-list-item>
                <v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-icon>mdi-clock-time-two-outline</v-icon>
                </v-list-item-icon>

                <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-card>
                        <v-card-title>Stoppuhr</v-card-title>
                        <v-card-text class="title">00:00:00</v-card-text>
                        <v-card-actions>
                            <v-btn>Toggle!</v-btn>
                            <v-autocomplete
                                :items="tickets"
                            />
                        </v-card-actions>
                    </v-card>
                </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
        </v-list>


    </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>
```

Comment: You can try to listen to `update:mini-variant` event.

Comment: That's the solution. I created a data attribute "mini" and added the v-show directive to the icon and the card - but for the card negated.